# Executing system calls in a C program via strings?

Tags: c, system-calls, strace

I have an strace log and want to execute the system calls line by line in a C program. Of course these system calls would be in the form of strings.

For example:
"openat(AT_FDCWD, "filename", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4"

^This is one of the lines in my strace log. And I want to execute lines like these as system calls in my C program.
Is there a way to execute them? And also get the return values?

Comment: What is your *actual* problem this is supposed to solve? Why do you need to execute system calls from a trace? Right now, your question is very much an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The strace log contains system calls when reading a file (only open, read and lseek). I basically want to execute an lseek call i.e. lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) after every system call in the strace log in order to get the file pointer location, to keep track of the bytes read.